# Which formula should I use to add column E values, grouped by year?

Tags: excel-formula, worksheet-function

For example, for year 2023, that formula should return sum of E3:E4, and when i drag down that formula, it should return, for 2022, sum of E5:E8.

[image: My Excel Sheet]

`=SUMIF(B2:B162, YEAR(B2)=2023, E2:E162)`

I tied this formula for the year 2023 only, but this didnt returned the desired answer.

Comment: You can post sample data using https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables. That way not everybody interested in helping you needs to retype every cell's data to start helping.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `Year`-function within `SumIf`

Use `Sumproduct` instead like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT($E$2:$E$162 * (YEAR($B$2:$B$162) = H2))`

It will sum all cells from E whenever Year of accordin`g payment date equals the value from H2.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use [the `SUMIF` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b), I would recommend using [the `SUMIFS` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b), which accepts *multiple* criteria.

**N.B.** `SUMIFS` moves the range to be summed to become the *first* argument, and makes it *Mandatory* — unlike `SUMIF` where it was the *last* argument, and was *Optional*.

```
=SUMIFS($E$2:$E$162, $B$2:$B$162, ">=" & DATE($H2, 1, 1), $B$2:$B$162, "<" & DATE($H2+1, 1, 1))
```

"Sum the values in Column E, where Column B is on-or-after 1st January of *this* year, **and** Column B is before 1st January of *next* year"